# AngularJs Directive element children gives empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Im trying to fetch innerHTML of the selected node on options

`<i class="before"></i>` tag should receive text from the selected or the first option on page load from same group. But only hard-coded dropdown get value on load, but dropdown from ngRepeat doesnt gets anything.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.investments = [
      {"name": "AARP Operating Funds"},
      {"name": "Some Big Title"},
      {"name": "I hatez IE8"},
      {"name": "I Love FF DeveLoper Edition"},
      {"name": "Give Me Some Sunshine"}
    ];

    $scope.investment = $scope.investments[0].name;


  })
  .directive('dropdownSelectBox', function(){


    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

      //.filter('option[value="' +  element.find('select').val() + '"]').text()

      console.log(element.find('select').children());

      if (element.find('select').val() == '') {
        element.find('i').text($('select').eq(0).text());
      } else {
        element.find('i').text(element.find('select').children()[0].innerHTML);
      }

      element.find('select').bind('change', function(){                    
          element.find('i').text($(this).find(':selected').text());
      });
      
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <span class="dropdown" dropdown-select-box="">
      
      <i class='before'></i>
      <select id="timePeriod">
          <option value="7" selected="selected">Last 7 Days </option>
          <option value="30">Last 30 Days </option>
          <option value="60">Last 60 Days </option>
          <option value="current">Current Year </option>
          <option value="prior">Prior Year</option>
      </select>

    </span>


    <span class="dropdown" dropdown-select-box="">
      
      <i class='before'></i>
      <select ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in investments | orderBy:'name'" ng-model="investment"></select>

    </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get be able to manipulate 'element' I just moved jquery script link before angularjs.

DEMO: http://runnable.com/VK5RPx_xRDp8aqF_/angularjs-crossbrowser-select-dropdown-for-jquery-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use ng-model:

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.investments = [
      {"name": "AARP Operating Funds"},
      {"name": "Some Big Title"},
      {"name": "I hatez IE8"},
      {"name": "I Love FF DeveLoper Edition"},
      {"name": "Give Me Some Sunshine"}
    ];

    $scope.investment = $scope.investments[0];
    $scope.period = 'Last 7 Days';

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <span class="dropdown" dropdown-select-box="">
      
      <i class='before'>{{period}} {{investment.name}}</i>
      <select id="timePeriod" ng-model="period">
          <option value="Last 7 Days" selected="selected">Last 7 Days </option>
          <option value="Last 30 Days">Last 30 Days </option>
          <option value="Last 60 Days">Last 60 Days </option>
          <option value="Current Year">Current Year </option>
          <option value="Prior Year">Prior Year</option>
      </select>

    </span>


    <span class="dropdown" dropdown-select-box="">
      
      <i class='before'></i>
      <select ng-options="opt.name for opt in investments | orderBy:'name'" ng-model="investment"></select>

    </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But ```<i class='before'></i>``` has to be empty. because in a page there are about 6-7 dropdown's and I don't want to add models each time, plus model names has to be different each time and that will because me to create new controller for each dropdown. Thats wont make sense.

Comment: Then it's better to encapsulate dropdown and <i> tag inside directive template.

Comment: I cannot create template since in this case as u can see 1 dropdown is hardcoded and another comes from ngOptions from controller.

Comment: You can move data for first dropdown from HTML to controller. As you can see angular doesn't have so much functions to parse HTML structure as jQuery does. It's not good approach to rely on DOM structure that much as in you code example.